# Rails 5: Issue with number of returned datasets when combining eager_load, left_joins and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, left-join, limit

I'm displaying a list (with pagination and different search functions) that contains 3 kinds of objects:

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :samples
end

class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tree
  has_many :projects_samples
  has_many :projects, through: :projects_samples
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects_samples
  has_many :samples, through: :projects_samples
end
```

Let's say my samples table contains just 5 samples, each of which belongs to a tree.
The first sample belongs to 2 projects, the other samples do not belong to any project.

I'm executing the following query which i'm expecting to return 3 datasets as a result:

```
result = Sample.eager_load(:tree).left_joins(:projects).limit(3)
```

What I get is only 2 datasets.
As soon as I remove one project from the first sample I get 3. Adding one more projects returns only one result.

There are also differences when counting the results:

```
result.length #2
result.size #2
result.count #3
```

I stumbled across this behaviour when I noticed my paginator gem (will paginate 3.1.6) to display just 6 instead of 10 entries on the first page.

Rails 5.1.5, Ruby 2.5.0

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Watch SQL query generated by `Sample.eager_load(:tree).left_joins(:projects).limit(3)`

Comment: @Pavel Mikhailyuk, I already did. The query is ok and returns the correct number of records (3) when copied into the postgres terminal!

Comment: Record is not equal to Model instance. Watch carefully, how many _distinct_ Sample IDs in that 3 records

Comment: Ok good point, you are right, there are only 2 distinct sample IDs in the output... anyway, this doesn't yet help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What I could do to get a correct number of results is to use includes instead of left_joins. But then the search result for projects contains only matching ones.

Comment: There is no "correct number". You should not mix eager_load with left_joins and limit. At first you have to build SQL query which suites your goals (may be through sub-select, may be someth. else) and then "translate" it on "ActiveRecord language".